# which database should i use for multi-value column

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, sqlite, database-schema

I don't know much about databases. I have a table on paper that have 4 or 5(1 for id) columns. One is primary and single value while others columns are secondary and can have multiple-value. Now i have some values and i have to search those value in secondary columns and return highest matched primary column. i.e

```
Id        Primary        Secondary_1      Secondary_2    Secondary_3
1         ABCD           12,11,9          51,52          77
2         ABCE           9,15,17          12,14,7        71,77
3         ABEF           8,9,14,12        51,7           77,71
4         ABEG           7,9,15           52,14          77,78
```

Secondary columns can have string type. Now suppose i have to search (8,9,14,77)
it should return ABEF. if search(9,51,77) it should return (ABCD,ABEF) and so on. So my problem is how i store database which schema should i use for this type of problem.

Comment: Is there a reason why there are 3 secondaries?

Comment: The more urgent point is that this is **very bad design**. If you search this site you will find many questions from developers trying to query data from "multi-value" columns. That is not how SQL works, and the resulting queries are horrible, the performance is horrible and the database will inevitably end up in a corrupted state. If you're going to use a database do some proper data modelling. Otherwise use a JSON document store or some similar free fire zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create 3 tables additionally to the primary table, and use foreign keys to connect their rows to the primary table:

1. primary table: *Id, Primary*
2. secondary table 1: *ForeignId, Value*
3. secondary table 2: *ForeignId, Value*
4. secondary table 3: *ForeignId, Value*

Then, create a foreign key on all "ForeignId" columns, connected with the "Id" column of the primary table.

Of course names of these columns are horrible. Don't name them "Value", be more precise.

The goal is to have single values in one field, not multiple ones. With such a normalized design, you can query your secondary tables with simple string comparisons, while joining your primary table rows with the matched rows.